# Why the state variable array content cannot be show in the div?

Tags: reactjs

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ivfpbt?file=src%2FMessageBox.js) is my code.

I want to show the current time in the `div` every 10 seconds.

```
setInterval(()=>{
      let now=new Date();
      messageBox.current.addMsg(now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds());
},10000)
```

However, the array content can be shown in the console only.
I am using the `forEach` loop to show the message in the `div`.

```
{messagesList.forEach(message=>{
              <div>{message}</div>
          })}
```

Would you tell me what's happening, why the `forEach` loop not working?

Comment: Please update your question to include a minimal, complete, and reproducible code example, and try to provide a bit more context and details about the issue, any debugging you've tried, and what, if any, error messages are (with stacktrace). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tying to render with `forEach`, however `forEach` doesn't return the jsx element (in fact returns undefined). You should use `.map`:

```
{messagesList.map((message, index)=> ( //Implicit return
         <div key={index}>{message}</div> 
  ))}
```

Comment: `.forEach` is a void return, surely you meant to *actually* use `.map` in the code snippet, right?

Comment: Are you referring to each iteration? [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) say return value is `undefined` Edit: I forgot to change `forEach` to `map` in my answer, oops :D

Answer (score 1):

The important reason to use `Array.map()` instead `Array.forEach()` in React + JSX:

[image]

Actually, you should return something to show in JSX layout.